# Heroku + Rails run custom build tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I would like to include a test to be executed as part of the build process in Heroku. And if any of those tests fail I don't want Heroku to release the build.

Test:

```
e.g verify initialisation of *required* env variables
```

Therefore when I run

```
git push heroku master
```

I would like my test to be performed.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CircleCI for that. First integrate your app with CircleCI and then review the option **Require status checks to pass before merging** in branches > Protected branches section of your repository settings. Afterwards you will need to write some shell scripts and save it to scripts in your project folder.

You can check out this tutorial for CircleCI implementation for your app.

https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/language-ruby-on-rails/

For the deployment script you can use something like below. Create a file named production in script folder and inside;

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e

export RAILS_ENV='production'
export RACK_ENV='production'

[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow
git push git@heroku.com:myapp.git master:master
heroku run rake db:migrate --app myapp
heroku run rake db:seed --app myapp
```

The flow will be like this; you will create a pull request from your branch to master. After pull request is created, your tests will automatically start in CircleCI. If it passes, you would be able to merge the pull request to the master branch. Once it is merged, tests will run again and it will deploy the app as you would have defined in your circle.yml file.

You can find detail information about circle.yml configuration [here](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/) and you could use the above script in your circle.yml file like

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - ./script/production
```

I think a better practice would be repeating these steps for staging environment as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was considering a CI workflow. CircleCI seems like good way to go about it.

Comment: @PrakashRaman You're welcome. Also I was referring to Github about the repository settings but it's quite similar in almost all repository managements.